# Particle Instance Modifier "Amount" and "Offset"

Tags: modifiers, particles

hopefully a quick question. I am looking at Particle Instance Modifiers as I want to have a particle system that emits particles, however I want the particle system to have different particle materials like you can achieve using groups.

I noticed that in the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/modeling/modifiers/simulate/particle_instance.html) under "Further Options" it mentions "Amount" and "Offset", though I cannot find these options in the particle instance modifier dialogue box. I am using Blender 2.79 and have tried the "Experimental Feature Set" under the render options, but cannot find what I'm after.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks

Dan